# Httpconnection in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I am calling a web service from blackberry when I try to open a connection using `Http Connection` it throws uncaught exception.

```
"Uncaught Exception: Application is not responding: process terminated"
```

Everything is working fine if I use EVO or WIFI but in my network few services are blocked and URL I am passing in open connection is also blocked.

I am using this code

```
url="http://mywebservice/"+ PhoneNo + "/" + RegistrationNo+"/" + PinCode;
String URL = url +getConnectionString()+";ConnectionTimeout=20000";
con = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(URL,Connector.READ_WRITE,true);
```

Please suggest any solution or how can we check that if requested URL is available or blocked?

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess: You are opening connection via EDT - Event Dispatch Thread (main app thread) this thread can not be used for time consuming operations (connection handling in your example). You need to do these tasks on different threads.